# How to properly handle default variables values being incorrect

Tags: java

This is probably a basic question, better explained through code:

```
    public void checkStatus {
        int status = UNKNOWN;
        if (somecondition) {
             status = STATUS_UP;
        } elseif (someothercondition) {
             status = STATUS_DOWN;
        }
    }
```

So the problem is, by definition I do not know all the possible conditions that might affect the STATUS, and I didn't want the compiler to throw 'my not be defined' error by not initializing the status local variable.

Bottom line my app won't work with a status set to UNKNOWN, I've just set it to shut up the compiler.

Question: how can I approach this elegantly, I've considered throwing an fatal exception at the end of the method should the status still be set to UNKNOWN, but that feels a bit 'ugly'.

Thank you.

Comment: If your app can't deal at all with that condition, throwing sounds perfectly reasonable.

Comment: If your app won't work, then the best thing is to inform the client by throwing the appropriate exception, instead of waiting for stuff to break later on

Comment: You haven't any way when your condition(s) is false and you won't throw any `Exception` also, what do you do? Answer is: You must choose one of two ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always put a `throw` at the end of the `if / then / else` chain, and do not assign the default value to the variable upfront. If the exception is thrown, it tells me not only that the application cannot continue, but also reports the reason why it cannot proceed. Moreover, it does that as soon as it finds out that it cannot proceed, which is very desirable for error reporting (generally, you want to report an error as soon as possible).

There is one special case, when you structured your code in such a way that the combination of `somecondition`s is such that you *never* run off the tail of the `if / then / else` chain, but the compiler cannot verify it automatically. For example, you validated the input before, and you know that there is no path through your code that can change it. In this specific case you should use an assertion rather than throwing an exception, because it indicates an error with your reasoning about your code, rather than a simple coding error.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the some default value of status variable in only else condition so that that if any`if` condition is not passed then at-least status get some default value.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you try an enum instead of integers.

Your code could work with an UNKNOWN status - it's what you return from the else clause if you're writing if/else if/else or the default condition if you use switch.

Throwing an exception can work as well.  It's a design choice that's yours to make.  You should use an exception if an unknown status is truly an exceptional situation.  If it's common, I'd lean towards the enum.

Answer (score 1):

You can either assert or throw an exception.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html